# Alter exposed form with multiple exposed filters

Tags: views

I would like to change the default value of my exposed form. But the issue is, I work with multiple selects. So the values of the second select changes depending on the value of the first select...

I've tried with `hook_pre_views`, `hook_pre_build`,... but nothing seems to do the thing I meant to do...

Anyone with some suggestions or advice?

Comment: Try this module https://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters

Comment: Not quite exactly what I had in mind... I would like to change the default value of the two filters.

Comment: You can't use hook_form_alter? Can you explain what doesn't work exactly? And what you tried so far.